# How to work with Rows/Columns from CSV files?

Tags: python, csv, rows

I have about 10 columns of data in a CSV file that I want to get statistics on using python. I am currently using the import csv module to open the file and read the contents. But I also want to look at 2 particular columns to compare data and get a percentage of accuracy based on the data. 
Although I can open the file and parse through the rows I cannot figure out for example how to compare:

Row[i] Column[8] with Row[i] Column[10]

My pseudo code would be something like this:

**category** = Row[i] Column[8]
**label** = Row[i] Column[10]

```
if(category!=label):
   difference+=1
   totalChecked+=1
else:
  correct+=1
  totalChecked+=1
```

The only thing I am able to do is to read the entire row. But I want to get the exact Row and Column of my 2 variables  **category** and **label** and compare them.

How do I work with specific row/columns for an entire excel sheet?

Comment: Each row read by the `csv.reader` is a list, so row[0] is the first column, and row[1] is the second. You can read all the row into a list of list and then be able to access any of them randomly.

Answer (score 0):

convert both to pandas dataframes and compare similarly as [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/comparing-and-matching-column-values-in-different-excel-files-using-pandas-a25172f0ff4d). Whatever dataset your working on using the [Pandas module](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/), alongside any other necessary relevant modules, and transforming the data into lists and [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), would be first step to working with it imo.

I've taken the liberty and time/ effort to delve into this myself as it will be useful to me going forward. Columns don't have to have the same lengths at all in his example, so that's good. I've tested the below code (Python 3.8) and it works successfully.

With only a slight adaptations can be used for your specific data columns, objects and purposes.

```
import pandas as pd 
A = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\query_sequences.csv') #dropped the S fom _sequences
B = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\Sequence_reference.csv')

print(A.columns)
print(B.columns)

my_unknown_id = A['Unknown_sample_no'].tolist() #Unknown_sample_no
my_unknown_seq = A['Unknown_sample_seq'].tolist() #Unknown_sample_seq

Reference_Species1 = B['Reference_sequences_ID'].tolist()
Reference_Sequences1 = B['Reference_Sequences'].tolist() #it was Reference_sequences

Ref_dict = dict(zip(Reference_Species1, Reference_Sequences1)) #it was Reference_sequences
Unknown_dict = dict(zip(my_unknown_id, my_unknown_seq))

print(Ref_dict)
print(Unknown_dict)

Ref_dict = dict(zip(Reference_Species1, Reference_Sequences1))
Unknown_dict = dict(zip(my_unknown_id, my_unknown_seq))

print(Ref_dict)
print(Unknown_dict)

import re
filename = 'seq_match_compare2.csv'
f = open(filename, 'a') #in his eg it was 'w'


headers = 'Query_ID, Query_Seq, Ref_species, Ref_seq, Match, Match start Position\n'
f.write(headers)

for ID, seq in Unknown_dict.items():
    for species, seq1 in Ref_dict.items():
         m = re.search(seq, seq1)
         if m:
              match = m.group()
              pos = m.start() + 1
              f.write(str(ID) + ',' + seq + ',' + species + ',' + seq1 + ',' + match + ',' + str(pos) + '\n')

f.close()
```

And I did it myself too, assuming your columns contained integers, and according to your specifications (As best at the moment I can). Its my first try [Its my first attempt without webscraping, so go easy]. You could use my code below for a benchmark of how to move forward on your question. 
Basically it does what you want (give you the skeleton) and does this : "imports csv in python using pandas module, converts to dataframes, works on specific columns only in those df's, make new columns (results), prints results alongside the original data in the terminal, and saves to new csv. It's as as messy as my python is , but it works! personally (& professionally) speaking is a milestone for me and I Will hopefully be working on it at a later date to improve it readability, scope, functionality and abilities [as the days go by (from next weekend).]

```
# This is work in progress, (although it does work and does a job), and its doing that for you. there are redundant lines of code in it, even the lines not hashed out (because im a self teaching  newbie on my weekends). I was just  finishing up on getting the results printed to a new csv file (done too). You can see how you could convert your columns & rows into lists with pandas dataframes, and start to do calculations with them in Python, and get your results back out to a new CSV. It a start on how you can answer your question going forward
#ITS FOR HER TO DO MUCH MORE & BETTER ON!! BUT IT DOES IN BASIC TERMS WHAT SHE ASKED FOR.

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import itertools #redundant now'?

A = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\book6 category labels.csv')

A["Category"].fillna("empty data - missing value", inplace = True)
#A["Blank1"].fillna("empty data - missing value", inplace = True)
# ...etc 

print(A.columns)

MyCat=A['Category'].tolist()
MyLab=A['Label'].tolist()

My_Cats = A['Category1'].tolist()

My_Labs = A['Label1'].tolist()
#Ref_dict0 = zip(My_Labs, My_Cats) #good to compare whole columns as block, Enumerate ZIP 19:06 01/06/2020 FORGET THIS FOR NOW, WAS PART OF A LATTER ATTEMPT TO COMPARE TEXT & MISSED TEXT WITH INTERGER FIELDS. DOESNT EFFECT PROGRAM

Ref_dict = dict(zip(My_Labs, My_Cats))

Compareprep = dict(zip(My_Cats, My_Labs))

Ref_dict = dict(zip(My_Cats, My_Labs))

print(Ref_dict)

import re #this is for string matching & comparison. redundant in my example here but youll need it to compare tables if strings.
#filename = 'CATS&LABS64.csv' # when i got to exporting part, this is redundant now
#csvfile = open(filename, 'a') #when i tried to export results/output it first time - redundant

print("Given Dataframe :\n", A)

A['Lab-Cat_diff'] = A['Category1'].sub(A['Label1'], axis=0)
print("\nDifference of score1 and score2 :\n", A)

#YOU CAN DO OTHER MATCHES, COMPARISONS AND CALCULTAIONS YOURSELF HERE AND ADD THEM TO THE OUTPUT

result = (print("\nDifference of score1 and score2 :\n", A))
result2 = print(A) and print(result)
def result22(result2):
    for aSentence in result2:
        df = pd.DataFrame(result2)
    print(str())
    return df


print(result2)
print(result22) # printing out the function itself 'produces nothing but its name of course

output_df = DataFrame((result2),A)
output_df.to_csv('some_name5523.csv')
```

Yes, i know, its by no means perfect At all, but wanted to give you the heads up about panda's and dataframes for doing what you want moving forward.

Comment: Your csv input file can be any number of columns lengths. And also contain differing lengths of columns. As long as there are 2 columns in it anywhere called Category1 and Label1 , you can run the code and test it yourself.